# Maximal independent sets in a graph $G$ versus maximal matchings in the line graph $L(G)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm a bit confused because of the answers in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194338/maximum-matchings-in-infinite-graphs .

I was thinking that an independent set in a graph $G$ corresponds to a matching in the [line graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) $L(G)$, and vice versa, but this gives the following confusing situation.

Let $G=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}K_n$ where $K_n$ is the complete graph on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq 1$. Note that this graph contains cliques of size $n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but it does not contain a clique of size $\omega$.

Let $G^c$ be the complement of the graph $G$ constructed above. Now $G^c$ contains maximal independent sets of size $n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (but no independent set of size $\omega$ because $G$ does not contain $K_\omega$).

Now we consider the line graph $L(G^c)$. Following this [argument](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194338/maximum-matchings-in-infinite-graphs/194347#194347) given by Tony Huynh all maximal matchings of $L(G^c)$ have the same cardinality. But not all maximal independent sets of $G^c$ have the same cardinality. How can this happen if maximal matchings in $L(G^c)$ correspond to maximal independent sets in $G^c$?

Comment: Do you mean that a matching in a graph corresponds to an independent set in the linegraph?

Comment: Oh ok - now I see my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gordon Royle's comment answers the question:  A matching in the graph corresponds to an independent set in the line graph, but independent sets in the graph don't usually correspond to matchings in the line graph. So your construction in the answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194338/maximum-matchings-in-infinite-graphs
actually doesn't work!

Comment: Thanks! Just for completeness's sake, could you include an example of a graph $G$ [without isolated points] and an independent set in $L(G)$ that does not correspond to a matching in $G$?

Comment: Sorry, I think you misread my answer.  Maybe I should phrase it differently.  What I meant was that it is not the case that independent sets in the graph correspond to matchings in the line graph.

Comment: My mistake, sorry! Can you give an example of a graph $G=(V,E)$ without isolated points and an independent set $I\subseteq V$ such that $I$ does not correspond to a matching in $L(G)$?

Comment: Ok, I should be more explicit.  There is a bijection between the matchings of a graph and the independent sets of the line graph.  More precisely, a matching in $G$ is literally the same as an independent set in $L(G)$.  On the other hand, if $I\subseteq V(G)$ is independent and consists of vertices of degree 1, then how do we choose edges in the line graph that somehow correspond to the vertices in $I$?  More precisely, let $G$ be the disjoint union of a bunch of edges.  Then $L(G)$ has vertices, but no edges and therefore no nonempty matchings.

Comment: Now I see - thanks!